# Setting PATH in kali linux to run Java Programs

Tags: java, linux

i am new to java & Linux, i have a problem regarding setting PATH in kali linux to run Java Programs, i have set the path as shown below after that i have executed the basic commands of java like java-version, javac, but when it comes to compile a java program it is showing the error as:& also why it is showing lower version of java, though even i have installed latest version of Java i.e JDK1.8.0_31, TIA

root@kali:~# PATH=/home/opt/jdk1.8.0_31/bin:$PATH

root@kali:~# export PATH

root@kali:~# java -version

java version "1.6.0_33"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.5) (6b33-1.13.5-2~deb7u1)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

root@kali:~# javac

root@kali:~# javac Hello.java

javac: file not found: Hello.java

Comment: Follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java) : here it is explained how to set the path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well set. The error message is exactly what is happening. The file is not there.

Comment: Thank you Alex, it is done i have putted that file on wrong place , but why it is showing me the older version when i have installed the latest version, after running the command java -version?

Comment: I see. First thing is modifying the JAVA_HOME variable to /home/opt/jdk1.8.0_31 and the modify the PATH to PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH. However, it is more important to move your JAVA_PATH and new PATH inside your .profile and .bash_rc files in your home folder, so they are set whenever you open a terminal. Otherwise you'll have to modify the PATH everytime you open a console.